# Headless tasks in React-Native timeout (Android)

Tags: java, android, react-native, background-process, headless

I am using headless tasks in RN android but I dont understand one thing, Timeout, does it mean how long I want the background process to work? I would like to work until I call stopService so do I have to specify the timeout there at all?

```
 return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig("headless_task", data, 5000, // timeout for the task
            true // optional: defines whether or not the task is allowed in foreground. Default
                 // is false
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The timeout is how long that task will be active. The maximum is 10 minutes. If it's a periodic task the minimum interval is 15 minutes. So there is a mandatory 5 minute down time. Just spin up another task during the down-time of the first task, and have it take over the process.